# Why do I get a "cannot execute csh..." error when I try to "sudo su"?

Tags: command-line, sudo, root

I get this error when I try do `sudo su`

```
reputa@reputa:~$ sudo su
Cannot execute csh: No such file or directory
```

`sudo -i` is working fine but I want to use `sudo su`. How do I make it happen?

Answer (score 3):

Your root's (su) profile is set to use [csh](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFkQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FC_shell&ei=_JsoUL_dGYqiigLPjoHQCg&usg=AFQjCNE8JYH8tm2n0jRJJIZ-NIJzRPzrkw) instead of the usual bash.

Run `sudo apt-get install tcsh` to install it, and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using csh shell as your root login shell. So you can either install the missing shell using @izx [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/175183/150504). Or just change the default login shell of your root to a valid, installed login shell.

You can change the login shell of the root with command:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/bash root
```

So now bash will become the login shell of root. You may change the shell to your needs.

Hint: you can get all shells in your system

```
cat /etc/shells
```

Answer (score -2):

You should better check your root's user default shell.

`sudo gedit /etc/passwd`

It should be `/bin/bash`

Comment: Directly editing `/etc/passwd` is a bad idea...

Comment: Thanks, you're true, the correct way is `sudo vipw /etc/passwd`